# Jquery 1.8.2 radio button won't check with prop('checked',true)

Tags: jquery

Trying to dynamically set a radio button.

This is the HTML

```
    <div class="field-block button-height" name="payment_types" id="payment-types">
        <label class="label"><b>Payment Methods</b></label>
        <div name="payment-type-cc" id="payment-type-cc">
            <input type="radio" name="paymentMethod" id="payment-method-cc" value="paypal" class="radio">
               <label for="payment-method-paypal">Pay with your Credit Card</label>
        </div>
        <div name="payment-type-skip" id="payment-type-skip">
            <input type="radio" name="paymentMethod" id="payment-method-skip" value="skip" class="radio">
                <label for="payment-method-skip">Skip payments for now. Register only.</label>
        </div>
</div>
```

Here are my jquery lines...

```
alert($('input:radio[name=paymentMethod]#payment-method-cc').val());
$('input:radio[name=paymentMethod]#payment-method-cc').prop('checked',true);
```

The alert returns "skip" so i know I have the right object. But the prop does not set the radio button.

Comment: It is working. http://jsfiddle.net/hN55m/

Comment: As an aside, why not `$('#payment-method-cc')`? (If your element has an id there's no need for all that other nonsense in your selector.)

Comment: the selector used in the OP only makes sense if the id's aren't unique

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solved the problem.

I'm using a theme and the theme adds additional UI elements.
I simply added the second line after the prop call and it works great. $('myobj').prop('checked',true); $('myobj').parents('span').addClass('checked');

For anyone who might be using the **developr theme** from themeforest, this is important to be aware of. The effects of the failed prop('checked',true) implementation is the checkbox does get set but the UI object being displayed does not display checked.

Right click on the object when your code does have it checked and inspect the UI elements (Firefox). You will see all the additional tags added. In my case, there was a span just above the  tag and I could see that the class value checked was present when the checkbox was check and not present when the object was not check.

Therefore, in my code, after I $('obj').prop('checked',true); I then add the code,  $('myobj').parents('span').addClass('checked'); to effect the displaying checkbox from the theme.

Answer (score 0):

```
<div class="field-block button-height" name="payment_types" id="payment-types">
    <label class="label"><b>Payment Methods</b></label>
    <div name="payment-type-cc" id="payment-type-cc">
        <input type="radio" name="paymentMethod" id="payment-method-cc" value="paypal" class="radio" />
           <label for="payment-method-paypal">Pay with your Credit Card</label>
    </div>
    <div name="payment-type-skip" id="payment-type-skip">
        <input type="radio" name="paymentMethod" id="payment-method-skip" value="skip" class="radio" />
            <label for="payment-method-skip">Skip payments for now. Register only.</label>
    </div>

<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.2.min.js"></script>
//<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.1.min.js"></script>

//works with 1.8.2 and 1.10.1

<script>
$(function(){

$("#payment-method-cc").attr('checked', 'checked');

});
</script>
```

Comment: I set the attribute, you set the property value. Although .prop is probably the better way to go after reading this page: http://api.jquery.com/prop/

Comment: Tried this and it still doesn't work. While checking other stackoverflow issues, I could use .attr('checked',true) as well. Using attr() is supposed to be before jquery 1.6. Since I'm using jquery 1.8.2, I published the question with prop. Thanks.

Comment: @user3097914 What does the console say?

Comment: Not really sure what you are looking for. Still figuring out firebug for jquery. But I did two things;
alert($('input:radio[name=paymentMethod]:checked').val()); after the .prop('checked',true) and it says that the entry 'value=paypal' is checked. 
Secondly, I ran console.log($('input:radio[name=paymentMethod]')); and it displays both radio buttons with none with the checked.

Comment: @user3097914 Not experiencing any problems here in Firefox; what version are you using?  Is this a local machine with a server running, or a local machine with a `file:///` protocol, or, an actual web server?

Comment: Server on the internet, http:// protocol. Nothing fancy going on. Using Firefox 26.0. Except for the radio button not showing selected, I'm getting the expected results. For example, I'm using a wizard so that when it goes to the next screen, the checked value is the expected result.
$('#wizard-step-player-fees').on('wizardleave', function(event) { alert($('input:radio[name=paymentMethod]:checked').val()); }
returns the proper checked value. It's just not showing checked.
There are some references to refresh the radio button but they didn't work either.

Comment: @user3097914 There isn't any chance you could link your site, is there?  Sometimes, its easier to debug the actual problem rather then the test case.

Comment: If you can provide your IP address, you can access the test case on the internet.

Comment: I assume that's the method you wish to use in order to Auth.  I'm not sure I'm comfortable sharing that; would not .htaccess be easier?  Though I realize in writing this you'd know that anyway via logs.

Comment: Do you use Skype? I don't have enough points to chat. We could take this conversation off here.

Comment: @user3097914 You currently have 18 rep..  Check the new questions queue, see if there are any edits you can make, then we can move this to chat; an accepted edit will give you 2 rep.

Comment: My solution works in JQuery 1.7.2, 1.8.2 and 1.10.1. I don't see why I got a -1 for the answer. Since the element had an ID i just used $("#payment-method-cc"). http://jsfiddle.net/patriotec/5B2jK/

Comment: Don't know why it has a -1 either. I didn't do it. Thanks for the help. At this point, the only thing I can think of is there is something in the code somewhere else causing the issue. Will look into it there.

Comment: -1 because it can't possible solve anything. If anything, it can cause code to not work as expected due to the .attr changes once the code is later upgraded to 1.9. Here's a demonstration of why .attr is the wrong way to change the checked property. http://jsfiddle.net/5B2jK/1/ It works the first time you use .attr, but subsequent uses of it will not work.

Comment: It doesn't solve the problem, and possibly introduces harmful bugs into the code.

Comment: Solved the problem. I'm using a theme and the theme adds additional UI elements.

Comment: I simply added the second line after the prop call and it works great. 
$('myobj').prop('checked',true);
$('myobj').parents('span').addClass('checked');